# Eclipse RCP: How to bring existing WorkbenchWindow to the top?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

In my RCP application, I created multiple WorkbenchWindow. Once multiple windows are opened, I would like to bring one of them on top programmatically. In my code, I can find out "`theWindow`" (type of `IWorkbenchWindow`) that I want to do that, but I'm not sure how to bring it to top (set it active?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rambler for the hint of forceFocus(), the actual function that does the trick is:

```
theWindow.getShell().forceActive();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following :

```
theWindow.getShell().setFocus();
```

If that doesn't work , try calling the `forceFocus()` on the same shell.

Comment: thanks for the hint, although focus (both set and force) didn't work for me, but forceActive() does the trick!